# At certain levels of functions, where does the final function returns the value?

Tags: python, function, return, python-module

This question may sound silly, but this is what I'm going through, I wrote a project with some modules, and certan levels of functions, as one function calls the another one and so on, the final function to return the result, a dictionary.

when I call the function on the first level, everything works well to the last funciton,

while at the last function,

printing the return dictionary works well while returning the dictionary with `return result` return `None`

I have a finite number of functions, spread over different modules.

```
# on module 1
def funciton_one(the_user_input):
    # code to process param at 
    # stage 1 if conditions are met
    function_two(parameter,the_user_input)

# on module 2
def function_two(parameter,the_user_input):
    # code to process param at 
    # stage 2 if conditions are met
    function_three(parameter,the_user_input)

# on module 3
def function_three(parameter,the_user_input):
    # code to process param at 
    # stage 3 if conditions are met
    function_four(parameter,the_user_input)

# on module 4
def function_four(parameter,the_user_input):
    # code to process param at 
    # stage 4 if conditions are met
    function_five(parameter,the_user_input)

# on module 5
def function_five(parameter,the_user_input):
    # code to process param at 
    # stage 5 if conditions are met
    function_six(parameter,the_user_input)

# on module 1
def function_six(parameter,the_user_input):
    # code to the process parameter and original parameter 
    # stage 6 if conditions are met
    return result

user_input = 'blahblah'
processed = function_one(user_input)
```

what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit:
Its like input is passed through all the functions, (the input to the first function is the original_parameter) and the parameter is processed values at different levels.

Update:
Much mess up, renaming the variables.
Thanks.

Comment: what is  `result`? Also you don't return from any function so you are going to return None by default

Comment: where does `result` come from?

Comment: Where `original_param' come from? And why `funciton_one' and not `function_one`?

Comment: result is a dictionary that is processed by` function_six`

Comment: @Clodion much mess up, original_param is the `user_input` in this case

Comment: @Marty: It's impossible to understand! We don't have sufficient code for that! And it's impossible to know where parameters come from!

Comment: @Clodion its like input is passed through all the functions, and the parameter is processed values at different levels.

Comment: There should be a variable to hold the value/dict/list in every function that you are passing to. Means there should be like `var=function1(...)` and so on

Comment: @cold_coder why I can't just the pass the parameter to another funciton than assigning a variable there? Its just how Django passes request, I guess.

Comment: Looking at the code I think I know what you want to achieve (answered below, hopefully) but you really should try to explain your problem more clearly next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you want to get your final output into `processed`? You need to return the final result to each of the functions, so `function_six` returns to `function_five`, returns to `function_four`, etc., until `function_one` returns into the `processed` variable.

I changed your code slightly to make it work (there was no `original_param` in `function_one`. Next time, please make sure your example code is valid before posting it.

```
# on module 1
def function_one(parameter):
    return function_two(parameter,parameter)

# on module 2
def function_two(parameter,original_param):
    return function_three(parameter,original_param)

# on module 3
def function_three(parameter,original_param):
    return function_four(parameter,original_param)

# on module 4
def function_four(parameter,original_param):
    return function_five(parameter,original_param)

# on module 5
def function_five(parameter,original_param):
    return function_six(parameter,original_param)

# on module 1
def function_six(parameter,original_param):
    result = "foobar"
    return result # returns foobar

user_input = 'blahblah'
processed = function_one(user_input)
print processed # prints foobar
```

Comment: @Clodion half book and half experience and you know what? I think so.

Comment: @Marty: yes, :-)  but function structure is quite simple but remain important!

Comment: @Clodion It was my first time ever calling function from function to function, I'm glad at last it worked!! And must note, there was a lot of parsing and processing of XML data, stressed!! ALL Tests Passed. Now get some sleep.

Answer (score 1):

You want each function to `return` the result of the call to the next one.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a variable to hold the value/dict/list in every function that you are passing to. Means there should be like var=function1(...) and so on

Comment: It was similar just as Jasper's solution.